# Can't get plots to stop painting when plot is breached without breaking the plot logic

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am building a reversal strategy in Pine Script version 5 for TradingView.

Imagine a scenario where you receive some reversal signal, let's say a breach of the upper or lower Bollinger Band, and you want to draw lines above and below at some multiple of ATR to act as a stop and a profit target. I can make this happen, however, what I can't seem to get to happen are two things:

1. If either line is breached, both lines should stop painting.
2. If a signal comes in the same direction it should be ignored, but if a signal comes in the opposite direction it should be taken, the lines then redrawn, and the process started over.

[First image, example of not stopping plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAgOB.png)
[Second image, example of multiple signals in same direction changing plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ4IK.png)

You can see an example of the flaw here in the first image. The lines draw in the correct location. However, when the upper line is breached they continue drawing until a new signal forms. In the second image you can see the other flaw, if a signal in the same direction comes it repositions the lines based on the new signal, which should only happen if a signal comes in the opposite direction.

Here is the relevant code. Thanks for any help you can provide! Even ChatGPT can't seem to figure out how to do this one.

```
if rangeDotUp and (atr_stop or atr_target)
    stopLine := close[1] - atr[1] * atr_stop_mult
    targetLine := close[1] + atr[1] * atr_target_mult
else if rangeDotDown and (atr_stop or atr_target)
    stopLine := close[1] + atr[1] * atr_stop_mult
    targetLine := close[1] - atr[1] * atr_target_mult
else
    stopLine := stopLine[1]
    targetLine := targetLine[1]

plot(stopLine, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.gray, linewidth=1, title="ATR Stop Line")
plot(targetLine, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.gray, linewidth=1, title="ATR Target Line")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.